# How to handle the `onKeyPress` event in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keypress, onkeypress

How can I make the `onKeyPress` event work in ReactJS? It should alert when **`enter (keyCode=13)`** is pressed.

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    add: function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            alert('Adding....');
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="one" onKeyPress={this.add} />    
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Test />, document.body);
```

Comment: Since [v0.11](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#improved-keyboard-event-normalization) React normalizes key codes into readable strings. I'd suggest using those instead of the keyCodes.

Comment: @RandyMorris react does not always normalize key codes correctly. For producing "+" will give you the key code value of 187 with shiftKey = true however the "key" value will resolve to "Unidentified".

Answer (score 370):

I am working with React 0.14.7, use `onKeyPress` and `event.key` works well.

```
handleKeyPress = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    console.log('enter press here! ')
  }
}
render: function(){
     return(
         <div>
           <input type="text" id="one" onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
        </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: and you can simutate it in tests it with : `Simulate.keyPress(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component.refs.input),{key:"Enter"});`

Comment: What is this weird syntax in the handleKeyPress function declaration? Mainly the equal sign between the name and the parameter is new to me.

Comment: @Waltari its ES6 syntax and is an experimental syntax.

Comment: What do you mean by experimental? I thought with ES6 "functionName(param) => {}" would work?

Comment: @Waltari It's ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which means `function handleKeyPress(event){...}`

Comment: It also binds `this`

Comment: Perhaps it's pedantic, but it's worth noting that it would be preferable to use the strict equality `===` check for `event.key == 'Enter'`.

Answer (score 85):

For me `onKeyPress` the `e.keyCode` is always `0`, but `e.charCode` has correct value. If used `onKeyDown` the correct code in `e.charCode`.

```
var Title = React.createClass({
    handleTest: function(e) {
      if (e.charCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter... (KeyPress, use charCode)');
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter... (KeyDown, use keyCode)');
      }
    },
    render: function() {
      return(
        <div>
          <textarea onKeyPress={this.handleTest} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

[React Keyboard Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events).

Comment: ..so if you're interested in using the arrow keys and/or other non-alphanumeric keys, onKeyDown is for you as they won't return a keyChar but a keyCode.

Comment: For those interested in trying out React keyEvents themselves, here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o43839o5r6) I created.

Answer (score 58):

```
render: function(){
     return(
         <div>
           <input type="text" id="one" onKeyDown={this.add} />
        </div>
     );
}
```

`onKeyDown` detects `keyCode` events.

Comment: Usually a thing as the enter key is detected via onKeyUp - this allows the user to stop the interaction if he decides to. using keyPress or keyDown executes immediately.

Answer (score 46):

Keypress event is deprecated, You should use Keydown event instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event

```
handleKeyDown(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) { 
        console.log('Enter key pressed')
  }
}

render() { 
    return <input type="text" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} /> 
}
```

Comment: It also supports `event.key === 'Enter'`. Take a look [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-modifier).

Answer (score 20):

If you wanted to pass a dynamic param through to a function, inside a dynamic input::

```
<Input 
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.doSearch(data.searchParam)
    }
  }}
  placeholder={data.placeholderText} />
/>
```

Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 16):

```
var Test = React.createClass({
     add: function(event){
         if(event.key === 'Enter'){
            alert('Adding....');
         }
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
            <input type="text" id="one" onKeyPress={(event) => this.add(event)}/>    
          </div>
        );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me using hooks, by accessing the window element

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
      console.log(e.key)
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You need to cleanup the eventlistener or it can potentially cause memory leak. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

Comment: It always should be cleaned up with window.removeEventListener(...). Callbacks are defined to listen to events over time. It takes memory and some processing power from the browser and the host computer. [post](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-cleanup-event-listeners-react)

Comment: `return () => window.removeEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress)`

Answer (score 11):

React is not passing you the kind of events you might think. Rather, it is passing [synthetic events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

In a brief test, `event.keyCode == 0` is always true. What you want is `event.charCode`

Comment: This is not affecting the question though. It doesn't change keyCode equaling 13 when Enter is pressed.

Comment: i just keep getting synthetic functions back for `e.key || e.keyCode || e.charCode`

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but I was trying to get this done in TypeScript and came up with this:

```
<div onKeyPress={(e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => console.log(e.key)}
```

This prints the exact key pressed to the screen. So if you want to respond to all "a" presses when the div is in focus, you'd compare e.key to "a" - literally if(e.key === "a").

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 8):

In addition to `onKeyPress` being deprecated, I consider that `onKeyUp` is a better option than `onKeyDown`, since it is not until the key is released that it is executed

```
<Element
   onKeyUp={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") console.log('Enter has press);
   }}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some challenges when it comes to keypress event. [Jan Wolter's article on key events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) is a bit old but explains well why key event detection can be hard.

A few things to note:

1. `keyCode`, `which`, `charCode` have different value/meaning in keypress from keyup and keydown. They are all deprecated, however supported in major browsers.
2. Operating system, physical keyboards, browsers(versions) could all have impact on key code/values.
3. `key` and `code` are the recent standard. However, they are not well supported by browsers at the time of writing.

To tackle keyboard events in react apps, I implemented [react-keyboard-event-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keyboard-event-handler). Please have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call **event.persist();** this method on your keyPress event.
Example:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const keyboardEvents = (event) =>{
       event.persist();
       console.log(event.key); // this will return string of key name like 'Enter'
   }
   return(
         <div onKeyPress={keyboardEvents}></div>
   )
}
```

If you now type `console.log(event)` in `keyboardEvents` function you will get other attributes like:

```
keyCode // number
charCode // number
shiftKey // boolean
ctrlKey // boolean
altKey // boolean
```

And many other attributes

Thanks & Regards

*P.S: React Version : 16.13.1*