# key binding in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

was trying to implement key binding in react.js. did some research, but still wondering what's the cleanest way to do it. For example,

```
if (event.keyCode == 13 /*enter*/) {
  function()
}
if (event.keyCode == 27 /*esc*/) {
  anotherfunction()
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/keypress-event-handling-in-reactjs maybe it will help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up binding the keydown event when the component mounted and unmounted:

...

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $(document.body).on('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
},

componentWillUnMount: function() {
  $(document.body).off('keydown', this.handleKeyDown);
},

handleKeyDown: function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 /*enter*/) {
    this.okAction();
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 27 /*esc*/) {
    this.cancelAction();
  }
},

render: function() {
  return this.state.showDialog ? (
    <div className="dialog" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
```

...

There's probably a better way to do this. The function is used as a part of a dialog component: https://github.com/changey/react-dialog

Comment: Wouldn't advise using jQuery to handle this when you could either use arrow functions to auto bind to handleKeyDown or set the bind up for handleKeyDown in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

step 1 : Define it in constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {        
    }
    this.handleEnterKeyPress = this.handleEnterKeyPress.bind(this)
  }
```

step 2 : Write it in render method

```
 render() {   
            return (             
                   <input className ="pageText" type="text" value= "value" onKeyPress = {this.handleEnterKeyPress} />                       
            )
          }
```

step 3 : write the respective function in the class

```
handleEnterKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.charCode == 13) {
      // your code
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my search component, please take a look at the onSearch function. I'm using no keyboard binding to accomplish the escape key clearing input and defocusing.

```
import React from "react"
import _debounce from "lodash.debounce"
import "./stylesheets/search"

export default class Search extends React.Component {

  displayName = "Search"

  static propTypes = {
    bucketName: React.PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
    onSearchUpdated: React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  state = {
    search: "",
    placeholder: "Search",
    bucketName: "",
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.delayedCallback = _debounce((event) => {
      let search = event.target.value
      this.setState({
        search,
      })
      this.props.onSearchUpdated(search, this.props.bucketName)
    })
  }

  onSearch = (event) => {

    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
      event.target.value = ''
      this.refs.input.blur()
    } else {
      this.refs.input.focus()
    }

    event.persist()
    this.delayedCallback(event)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12 search__container form-group">
            <input
              ref="input"
              className="form-control search__field"
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              name="search__field"
              id="search__field"
              type="text"
              onKeyDown={this.onSearch}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't yet have enough rep to comment on your answer yet, but I would like to suggest an improvement.

Try using event namespacing when you bind/unbind these. This is especially important when binding events to the body, as it allows you to unbind without disrupting any other bindings of the same type:

See: 
https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $(document.body).on('keydown.awesomeNamespaceName', this.handleKeyDown);
},

componentWillUnMount: function() {
  $(document.body).off('keydown.awesomeNamespaceName', this.handleKeyDown);
},

handleKeyDown: function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 /*enter*/) {
    this.okAction();
  }
  if (event.keyCode == 27 /*esc*/) {
    this.cancelAction();
  }
},
```