# Update/Append component into another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am new to react and am in learning phase. What i am trying to do is to have a todo list with a due date.
The following are my React components:

```
var TaskTitle = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="taskTitle">
                <textarea  ref="tskTitle" onBlur={this.props.handleTitleBlur} onChange={this.props.setTaskTitle} name="tasktitle[]" id="tasktitle" value={this.props.taskTitle} className="tasktitle" ref="tskTitle"></textarea>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Calendar Component

```
 var CalendarWithTime = React.createClass({
        componentDidMount: function() {
          this.myCalendarInput = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.showCal));
          var self = this;
          this.CalendarWithTime = this.myCalendarInput.datetimepicker({
            format:'Y-m-d H:m',
            onShow:function(){
                self.props.calendarOpen(); //Updating parent state
            },
            onClose:function(){
                self.props.calendarClosed();//Updating parent state
            },
            onChangeDateTime:function(dp,input){
                self.props.dateChange(dp,input); //Updating parent state
            }
          });
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div className="datetimeWrapper">
                    <div className="datetime clearfix">
                        <div ref="showCal" className="showCalendar">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Single Todo component

```
var ToDo = React.createClass({
    handleCalendarOpen:function(){
        this.setState({ canUpdate:false });
    },
    handleCalendarClose:function(){
        this.setState({ canUpdate:true });
        this.updateTaskData();
    },
    stateUpdate:function(obj){
        for(var key in obj){
            this.state[key] = obj[key];
        }
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {taskID:null,taskTitle:null,taskDueDateTime:null};
    },  
    setTaskTitle:function(event){
        this.setState({ taskTitle: event.target.value,canUpdate:false });
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps:function(newProps){
            this.setState({ 
                taskTitle: newProps.tskTitle,
                taskDueDateTime:newProps.dueDate, 
                canUpdate:true
            });
    },
    updateTaskTitle:function(event){
        this.setState({taskTitle:event.target.value,canUpdate:false});
        this.updateTaskData();
    },
    updateTaskData:function(){
        var self =this;

        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url: $('meta[name="baseurl"]').attr('content')+'api/save_task',
              dataType: 'json',
              method:'post',
              data:self.state,
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
                if(data.status){
                    self.setState({canUpdate:true});
                }                   
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.dataURL, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
        },500);
    },
    componentDidMount:function(){
            var seldate=this.props.tskDueDate,dueDate=null,dueTime=null,dueLabel=null;
            if(seldate){
                dueDate = moment(seldate,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                dueTime = moment(seldate,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a').format('hh:mm a'),
                dueLabel = moment(seldate,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a').format('MMM Do, hh:mm a');
            }
            this.setState({
                taskTitle:this.props.tskTitle,
                taskDueDateTime:this.props.tskDueDate,  
                canUpdate:true,
            });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tr className="resp-table">
                <td><TaskTitle taskTitle={this.state.taskTitle} setTaskTitle={this.setTaskTitle} canUpdate={this.state.canUpdate} handleTitleBlur={this.updateTaskTitle} onUpdate={this.stateUpdate} key={this.state.taskID +"0"+this.state.taskID} taskID={this.props.tskID} /></td>   
                <td><CalendarWithTime  calendarClosed={this.handleCalendarClose} calendarOpen={this.handleCalendarOpen} dateChange={this.handleDateChange} dueDateTime={this.state.taskDueDateTime} dueDate={this.state.taskDueDate} dueTime={this.state.taskDueTime} dueLabel={this.state.taskDueLabel} key={this.state.taskID +"2"+this.state.taskID} /></td> 
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

//Load Previous tasks if any

```
var PrevTaskList = React.createClass({
        loadTaskList:function(){
            $.ajax({
              url: $('meta[name="baseurl"]').attr('content')+'api/get_task/',
              dataType: 'json',
              method:'post',
              data:{wsID:$('body').attr('data-wsid')},
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
                if(data.status){
                    this.setState({taskListData: data.taskList});
                }                   
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.dataURL, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
        },
        componentWillMount: function() {
            this.loadTaskList();
            setInterval(this.loadTaskList,this.props.pollInterval); // to render any new task added by other users
        },
        render: function() {
            if(this.state.taskListData){
                var TaskNodes = this.state.taskListData.map(function(task){
                    return(
                        <ToDo key={task.task_id}  tskID={task.task_id} tskTitle={task.task_title} tskDueDate={task.task_due_date} />
                    );
                },this);

                return (
                        <table ref="taskTable" id="tasktable">
                            <tbody >
                                {TaskNodes}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                );
            }
        }
});
```

Rendering Final Component

```
ReactDOM.render(<PrevTaskList pollInterval="5000"/>,$('#taskWrapper').get(0));
```

Now how can i add a new task on pressing enter key in the text area(TaskTitle) component? i am confused here of where to provide the event and how to render a
empty task. Is my component modelling even right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Waiting for help.. hopefully

Comment: You'll want to pass a function from the parent that holds the list of tasks in local state, to the task component that you can call when you're ready to add the task. The parent (one with task state) then adds to the list of tasks.  The easiest way to do this is with a save button next to the text area. Otherwise you're going to have to listen to changes in the text area and figure out when the use presses the enter key and call the callback.

Comment: Hey @Nouphal.M have you tried the `onKeyPress` event?
Seems to me you want to do something like  this: 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/keypress-event-handling-in-reactjs)
Have a `onKeyPress` event check for the particular charCode, and have a callback that will save the titile.