# React keypress input

Tags: reactjs, function, keypress, onkeypress

> I'm trying to prevent some characters from being entered, but for some reason the ban does not happen. Where was I wrong?

```
render () {
    return <form>
        <input
            id="username"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            value={this.state.value}
            onKeyPress={this.pale_username.bind(this)}
        />
    </form>
}
```

and function

```
pale_username(key) {
    if((key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) //numbers
        && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) // AB
        && (key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) // ab
        && (key.charCode !== 36) // $
        && (key.charCode !== 38) // &
        && (key.charCode < 40 || key.charCode > 41) // ()
        && (key.charCode < 45 || key.charCode > 46) // -.
        && (key.charCode !== 95) // _
        && (key.charCode !== 127) // del
        && (key.charCode !== 8) // BackSpace
        && (key.charCode !== 46))
        return false;
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle the character 'ban' in an `onChange` handler. One reason is, what happens if someone copy and pastes something into your input? Preventing the input in a keyboard event handler will not work.

I would try something like this:

```
handleChange(e) {
  // Use whatever regex you need.
  const filteredInput = e.target.value.replace(/[abAB$&()-_.*]|\d+/g, '');
  this.setState(value: filteredInput)
}
```

And then use it in your input.

```
<input
  id="username"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Username"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you still tell me how not to list the locked ones, but to allow only some?)

Comment: I'll just put '^' in the beginning

Comment: Edited the regex. Also, I just looked at your question again. if you want to prevent backspace and delete, you should check if `event.target.value` is shorter than `this.state.value` before calling `setState`.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not think I will need this, because the user should be able to edit))

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyDown` detects `charCode` and `onKeyPress` detects `keyCode`. Try change it for `onKeyDown`

Comment: onKeyDown does not work for me, because I'm looking for charCode characters

Comment: look at this. it's a similar question with a similar answer!! i hope it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/keypress-event-handling-in-reactjs

Comment: I tried it. Problem still exists. I can still type characters like '#'

Comment: Thanks for trying) I'm very glad that you tried to help.) The decision above worked. Perhaps you too need help)