# Submit button working only if div is inside form - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having a input in react component, 
When the input is inside , Enter button will trigger a click, but if input is not wrapped inside form, Enter does not work,

Is wrapping input by form the only way to activate Enter button ?

```
    <div>
        <input name=“name” type="text"
           value={somevalue} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button  id=“searchbutton”
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            {search label}
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of HTML. You could also prevent this behavior and manually bind the keyup event to a method.

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use form?

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/how-to-handle-the-onkeypress-event-in-reactjs

Comment: Just to be clear: You **want** the Enter key in the `input` to trigger the button, right?

Comment: thats correct @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2):

> Is wrapping input by form the only way to activate Enter button ?

Your other option is to use a `keypress` handler on the `input` and check for the Enter key.

The reason it works when this is in a `form` is that browsers automatically click the submit button on a form if the form has only a single text `input` and the user presses Enter. Without the form, you don't get that automatic behavior.

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do with an `input` that I had created outside of a form. I had to create a separate `keypress` handler for it to handle the user pressing the enter key. This, for me, is the best solution to this if for some reason you don't want to use a form.

Comment: @OsamaKhalid - Right, which is why the OP sees the behavior he sees when this is in a `form`. I'm not sure why the comment...?

Answer (score 0):

```
//By default in form type of button is "submit". Change that to : 
    <button  type="button" id="searchbutton"
           onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
           {search label}
    </button>
```

Comment: My impression is that the OP **wants** the Enter key (in the `input`) to click the button. Changing it to a plain button will stop that.

Comment: He is calling the function on click, so it will work, from where ever it is clicked!

Comment: The OP has now confirmed that he wants pressing Enter in the `input` to click the button.